# What exactly does "expectation/variance exists" mean

Tags: probability

I often see words like the expectation/variance "exists". I wonder what's the exact definition for those in probability and statistics. In my opinion, expectation is a Lebesgue integral of real-valued function, and it does not exist if and only if both the positive and negative parts are infinite. Variance is an Lebesgue integral of nonnegative-valued function that involves the mean, and it does not exist if and only if the mean does not exist.

Am I right?

Comment: I'd say expectation does not exist if it is $\pm\infty$, or (as you say) if the integral is not well-defined. In all other cases, it does exist (Because it is just a number).

Answer (score 2):

We say the $n$-th moment of $X$ exists if $\mathbb{E}(|X|^n) < \infty$. Hence, expectation exists if $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < \infty$. For variance, you need a second moment, so we say variance exists if $\mathbb{E}(|X|^2) < \infty$.